# Is it true that $\det A=\det A^*$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_n$ and $A^*$ is conjugate of $A$.

Is it true that $\det A=\det A^*$?                                    .

Comment: It doesnt't. Take $A = i$.

Comment: Might you have meant the transpose rather than the conjugate? $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true in general:Let $\lambda_{i}$ be the eigenvalues of $A$, then the eigenvalues of $A^{*}$ are $\overline{\lambda_{i}}$, then $\det A = \prod_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}$ and $\det A^{*} = \prod_{i=1}^{n}\overline{\lambda_{i}} = \overline{ \prod_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}} = \overline{\det A}$.